# how to get memory address of each array's element in java?

Tags: java, arrays, unsafe

When I try to get memory adress of each element in array.I tried to run code as below

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import static sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe;

public class test_arr {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field theUnsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe u = (Unsafe) theUnsafeField.get(null);
        int[][] arr = new int[3][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(u.getAddress(arr[i][j]));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But i meet this error.
[A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6xX7.png)

I have looked the https://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/ But i can't fix this error.
if someone konws how to fix it,please tell me,thanks!

As suggested by the comments I changed the code.

```
public class test_arr {
private static long normalize(int value) {
    if (value >= 0) return value;
    return (~0L >>> 32) & value;
}

static long toAddress(Object obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object[] array = new Object[]{obj};
    Field theUnsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    theUnsafeField.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe u = (Unsafe) theUnsafeField.get(null);
    long baseOffset = u.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
    return normalize(u.getInt(array, baseOffset));
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    int[][] arr = new int[3][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            double random = Math.random();
            arr[i][j] = (int) (random);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            long address = toAddress(arr[i]);
            System.out.println((Long.toHexString(address)));
        }
    }
}
```

}

The output looks like you can infer the addresses of the array elements.But it's still not possible to know the exact position of each element.

```
d57431a7
d57431a7
d57431a7
d57431a7
d57431ab
d57431ab
d57431ab
d57431ab
d57431af
d57431af
d57431af
d57431af
```

I still want to know the exact memory address of each array element, how should I do that, thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/ is the better place to ask

Comment: Read the documentation of `getAddress`. It does not do what you try to do. You're trying to dereference the *value* of that array cell (which will be 0), which causes a segmentation fault (the native equivalent of a NPE).

Comment: seems like the `Unsafe` class is unsafe to use; from the [javadoc](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/4b1403d06b99b91ddd89ad6e54669b0595f1f8e5/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe.java#L257): "*Fetches a native pointer from a given memory address. If the address is zero, or ... , the results are undefined.*"

Comment: *`I still want to know the exact memory address of each array element`* Why would you need the actual address?   What is the use case for this? This has the indications of an XY problem.